# create tfrecord for object detection task

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I'm creating my dataset for a fine tuning task using tensorflow object detection api.

My directory structure is :

train/

-- imgs/

---- img1.jpg

-- ann/

---- img1.csv

where the csv, one per image, is `label, x, y, w, h`

I used this script to save the tfrecord:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from os import listdir
    import os
    from os.path import isfile, join
    import csv
    import json

    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util


    flags = tf.app.flags
    flags.DEFINE_string('output_path', '', 'Path to output TFRecord')
    FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

    LABEL_DICT = {}
    counter = 0

    def create_tf_example(example):
      # TODO(user): Populate the following variables from your example.
      height = 404 # Image height
      width = 720 # Image width
      filename = example['path'].encode('utf-8').strip() # Filename of the image. Empty if image is not from file

      with tf.gfile.GFile(example['path'], 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_image_data = fid.read()

      image_format = 'jpeg'.encode('utf-8').strip() # b'jpeg' or b'png'

      xmins = [] # List of normalized left x coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
      xmaxs = [] # List of normalized right x coordinates in bounding box
                 # (1 per box)
      ymins = [] # List of normalized top y coordinates in bounding box (1 per box)
      ymaxs = [] # List of normalized bottom y coordinates in bounding box
                 # (1 per box)
      classes_text = [] # List of string class name of bounding box (1 per box)
      classes = [] # List of integer class id of bounding box (1 per box)

      for box in example['boxes']:
        #if box['occluded'] is False:
        #print("adding box")
        xmins.append(float(int(box['x']) / width))
        xmaxs.append(float(int(box['w']) + int(box['x']) / width))
        ymins.append(float(int(box['y']) / height))
        ymaxs.append(float(int(box['h']) + int(box['y']) / height))
        classes_text.append(box['label'].encode('utf-8'))
        classes.append(int(LABEL_DICT[box['label']]))


      tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
          'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
          'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
          'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
          'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
          'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image_data),
          'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
          'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
          'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
          'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
          'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
          'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
          'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
      }))

      return tf_example

    def ex_info(img_path, ann_path):
      boxes = []
      head = ['label','x','y','w','h']
      with open(ann_path, 'r') as csvfile:
        annreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames=head)
        for box in annreader:
          boxes.append(box)
          LABEL_DICT[box['label']] = LABEL_DICT.get(box['label'], len(LABEL_DICT) + 1)

      ex = {
        "path" : img_path,
        "boxes" : boxes
      }

      return ex

    def main(_):
      writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(FLAGS.output_path)

      # TODO(user): Write code to read in your dataset to examples variable
      dataset_dir = "train"
      ann_dir = join(dataset_dir, "ann")
      imgs_dir = join(dataset_dir, "imgs")
      labelDest = "tfTrain/data/labels_map.pbtxt"

      imgs = [join(imgs_dir, f) for f in listdir(imgs_dir) if isfile(join(imgs_dir, f))]
      anns = [join(ann_dir, os.path.basename(im).replace("jpg","csv")) for im in imgs]

      for img,ann in zip(imgs,anns):
        example = ex_info(img,ann)
        #tf_example = create_tf_example(example)
        #writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())


      with open(labelDest, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outL:
        for name,key in LABEL_DICT.items():
          outL.write("item { \n  id: " + str(key) + "\n  name: '" + name + "'\n}\n")


      writer.close()


    if __name__ == '__main__':
      tf.app.run()
```

but then when I run the train script I got this error

> python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=./models/train
>   --pipeline_config_path=faster_rcnn_resnet101_coc
>           o.config
>           WARNING:tensorflow:From models/research/object_detection/trainer.py:257: create_global_step
>   (from tensorflow.contrib.framewo
>           rk.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
>           Instructions for updating:
>           Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
>           Traceback (most recent call last):
>             File "models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 135,
>   in load_labelmap
>               text_format.Merge(label_map_string, label_map)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 525, in Merge
>               descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 579, in MergeLines
>               return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 612, in MergeLines
>               self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 627, in _ParseOrMerge
>               self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 727, in _MergeField
>               merger(tokenizer, message, field)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 815, in _MergeMessageField
>               self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
>             File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 695, in _MergeField
>               (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
>           google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 23:20 : Message type "object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem" has no field named
>   "s".
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "train.py", line 184, in <module>
>         tf.app.run()
>       File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
> ```
>
> line 126, in run
>               _sys.exit(main(argv))
>             File "train.py", line 180, in main
>               graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
>             File "models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 264, in train
>               train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
>             File "models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue
>               tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
>             File "train.py", line 121, in get_next
>               dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next()
>             File "models/research/object_detection/builders/dataset_builder.py", line
>   155, in build
>               label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file)
>             File "models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py",
>   line 245, in **init**
>               use_display_name)
>             File "models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 152,
>   in get_label_map_dict
>               label_map = load_labelmap(label_map_path)
>             File "models/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 137,
>   in load_labelmap
>               label_map.ParseFromString(label_map_string)
>           TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>
> I do not understand what's the problem. In the tfrecord? in the
>   labels.pbtxt? or in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just solved debugging tensorflow. Ended up my labels, although in utf-8 format, are not easily read by tensorflow because of some weird characters like & ù à. Removing from the csv let the train start